# Hide output from proc_open command

Tags: php, windows, process, console

I habe a question. Maybe it is a beginner one, but actually I can't find a solution to my problem and I haven't worked before with this command. Maybe someone can give me a hint.

I'm using `php` `proc_open` command to run `pdflatex.exe` to produce a PDF file from a `tex` file.
The code looks like this:

```
$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),  
    1 => array("pipe", "w"), 
    2 => array("file", "D:/Freigabe/error.txt", "a")
);

$cwd = str_replace("\\", "/", __DIR__) .'/Tex/Working';
$env = null;
$this->execute = '"' .str_replace('/','\\',env('PDFLATEXENGINE', 'C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/pdflatex.exe')) .'" -jobname="' .str_replace('.pdf','',$this->publicPdfFile) .'" -output-directory="' .str_replace("\\", "/", $this->pdfTargetPath) .'" "' .str_replace("\\", "/", str_replace(".tex","",$this->workingFilePath));
$process = proc_open('"' .$this->execute .'"', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);
if (is_resource($process)) {
    fwrite($pipes[0], '<?php print_r($_ENV); ?>');
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    $return_value = proc_close($process);
}
```

One example of a command is this one:

```
$this->execute = '"D:\Program Files\TeXLive\texlive\2019\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe" -jobname="Rechnung_000036-19" -output-directory="D:/Files/Company/Tool/app/Classes/Rechnung/LaTex/Output/" "D:/Files/Company/Tool/app/Classes/Rechnung/LaTex/Output/Rechnung_FUmtC1P7lknTzvDfstMM_000036-19"';
```

This works fine, but the command itself produces some output when it generates the PDF file. With this code above, the output of the command is printed to my webpage and it looks like this:

[image]

I also know, why this is being printed. It is just because of this code line:

```
fwrite($pipes[0], '<?php print_r($_ENV); ?>');
```

But when I comment out the `print_r()` command the PDF file is no longer being produced.
I checked for a solution to supress the output of the command window. I only found `> /dev/null`, but this I also get not to work.

Has anyone a solution or a hint for my problem?
Many thanks in advance!
If any information is missing, please let me know. I will update the original post then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. I can suppress the `console` output with simply adding `>nul` to the command. So this is my solution:

```
$process = proc_open('"' .$this->execute .'" >nul', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);
```